# How did the kitchen get messed up?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-sixth-sense

In The Sixth Sense there is a scene where Cole is in the kitchen and Lynn walks out of the room talking to him.  She returns and finds all of the drawers and cupboards open.  She screams in fright as there was no sound made and the amount of time she was gone was not enough for all of these to be opened.

However, even if the ghosts did it - how did they do it so fast without making any noise?

Comment: Assuming the ghosts did this (which they did), how do ghosts do anything? We don't know. M. Night Shyamalan does a great job in this movie of getting the hackles on the back of our necks to stand up. I don't think this is a plot-inconsistency, in fact, I'd suggest it's very consistent when we think of ghosts in movies. But, this is JMHO, so am leaving it here as a comment.

Comment: I thought this until yesterday evening when I was watching the Last Exorcism 2 (no idea why this came to me).  The ghosts seem to walk around, talk, move things etc as they did when they were alive (the girl's ghost pushes the box towards him with her hands).  They are not shown to be using telekinesis or anything similar that I can recall.

Comment: It seemed kind of like an homage (or rip-off) of the chairs-on-the-table "TV People" bit from Poltergeist. In my opinion the Poltergeist scene was more intense and unexpected.

Comment: Could the divebomber leave a note to explain the issues?

Comment: I don't think it can be answered..I mean your asking how can ghosts can do something..they're ghosts

Comment: Surely it can be answered by someone who is more observant than me noticed a ghost doing something similar in the film or someone explained at some point that they can move multiple things at the same time etc.  I recall nothing showing that ghosts can do this and it seems to require behaviour that ghosts who don't know they are dead would not exhibit.  I might be wrong though so I asked.

Comment: As vedran said in his answer.."I don't think one can get more then a speculative answer"..I agree..they're ghosts..in the plebty of films they appear in, they can do things that don't have or need an in universe explanation just because they're ghosts..I don't think they' re can be a non-speculative answer on this and thats why I made the down vote

Comment: But don't you agree that there could be a non speculative answer to this if I had missed something or not made a relevant connection in the film?

Comment: Speculative or not, I don't really see the reason for the downvote. It's a legit question, even if we agree that the answer cannot be found inside the movie.

Comment: Wow people don't handle down votes too we'll..I just think it's a pretty bad question..it's a question about how ghosts do things..hAha this site is getting worse

Comment: The question was more about whether I had missed anything in the film which explained this, was there a reference to ghosts being able to move particularly quickly or a mention of some ghosts being able to control multiple objects at the same time etc.? In other news, I always like to know why people have downvoted my Qs or As as it might help me improve them.

Answer (score 2):

Who's to say that it was just one ghost? Maybe there were many ghosts, i.e., one ghost per each drawer and cupboard. Or they're capable of doing more than we've seen them do.

I don't think that one can get more than a speculative answer on this. It was not explained in the movie, which is quite normal, since it's a typical suspense-raising scene, and explaining those beats their purpose. But I think that it was purposefully done that way, so that it is obvious that Cole couldn't have done it (alone).

As for your comment about ghosts "not shown to be using telekinesis or anything similar", they do move objects. Remember that first girl that Cole has helped? They were under her bed, and she pushed that box with the video tape to him, if I remember the movie correctly.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in my comment.  She seemed to be using her hands though?

Comment: Yes, she did. However, since ghosts are bodyless, do "hands" really have any effect? It's still a telekinesis (*[the direct influence of mind on a physical system that cannot be entirely accounted for by the mediation of any known physical energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telekinesis)*), since there can be no (material) contact. Besides, we never saw who did the kitchen mess, so these ghosts may have used their hands as well.

Comment: If they pulled the drawers 'conventionally' then wouldn't cole's mother had heard the noise of all those drawers being quickly opened?

Comment: "Conventionally" has nothing to do with it. The noise comes from dragging wood against wood, regardless of what is dragging it (hand or some mental power). In other words, the faster the drawers are drawn, the more noise is heard. But, if all the drawers were drawn at the same time, then it could've been done relatively slowly and practically noiselessly.

Answer (score 1):

In the suicide ghost's scene, all the cabinets are shown open. I assumed it was her and she frequents the house, likely because it's where she died. Doesn't explain how they were opened so fast - that's likely one of those unexplainable theatric things.